# Finding an upperbound on $f(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I am stumped trying to prove that there exists a real number $c$, such that $f(n)\leq cn^4$ for most natural numbers $n$.

$$f(n) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       10, &n=10\\
       3f\left(\left\lfloor \frac{2n}{5} \right\rfloor \right) + 6n^4,&n\geq 1
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

I have computed some values of $f(n)$ from $0-9$ and have chose my constants that seem to make $f(n)\leq cn^4$ true: $c=7$ and $n>4$. However, I don't know how to prove that $c$ is valid. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use (strong) induction:

for $n$ big enough, such as $k< n\implies f(k) \le Ck^4$,
$$f(n) = 
3f\left(\left\lfloor \frac{2n}{5} \right\rfloor \right) + 6n^4
\le \left[ 3C \frac {2^4}{5^4} + 6\right]n^4
\le \left( 0.08 C + 6\right)n^4
\le Cn^4
$$
 as soon as
$$
 0.08 C + 6 \le C \Leftarrow C  \ge 7
$$
Then check that $7$ is convenient for the first values (until $n > \lfloor \frac{2n}{5} \rfloor $), and you are done.

Comment: @mookid...Why did you put $3^3$ instead of $5^3$ at your second "step"

Comment: this is a typing mistake. but it remains true, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: Yeah the later statements still hold true. Just a clarification, what do you mean when you say "check that 15 is convenient for the first values"?

Comment: this is induction. so you need to initialize it. I added a correction.

Comment: Oh I see, in other words, we need to prove our base case, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18354/discussion-between-wonggr-and-mookid).

Comment: One last question, how do we solve for C then?

Comment: this is the point of the induction: both find a $C$ for which everything works, and the justification

Comment: You never seem to use $k$, why do we have to construct it then?

Comment: I use $k = \lfloor 2n/5 \rfloor$ in the first inequality.

Comment: Can we move this to a chat so we can speak a little better?